# Are there other uncommon calculation methods?

Tags: calculus, limits

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYd3a.png)

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{（(x+h)^h-1）}{h}$

$\lim _{h\to0} \frac{(1+h/x)^{(x/h)h}}{h}$

What method can I use to get the result? I don't understand what method is used here.

I'm a little curious, is there any way.Honestly, I’m not sure because there is no other process here.

Thanks for your replies.I think I am missing something, this is a $\frac{0}{0}$,Can I not apply the L'Hospital's rule.I think how he used other methods to calculate this limit.

$t=(x+h)^{h}-1；h=\log _{(x+h)}{(t+1)}=\frac{\ln {(t+1)}}{\ln {(x+h)}};t\to0$

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{（(x+h)^h-1）}{h}=\lim _{t\to0}{h\to0} \frac{t}{\log _{(x+h)}{(t+1)}}=\ln{(x+h)}\frac{t}{ln{(t+1)}}$

$\lim_{t\to0}(1+t)^{1/t}=e$

$\lim _{t\to0} \frac{t}{\ln(t+1)}=\frac{1}{\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t}}=\frac{1}{\ln((1+t)^{1/t})}=1$

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use L'Hôpital's rule, since applying it would require us to know the derivatives of the top and bottom (but that is the very thing which we are trying to prove!).

Comment: Try to spot the mistake in this argument that $\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$: $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2(x+h)}{1}=2x \, .$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^x$

take logarithm

$$\log f(x)=x \log x$$

differentiate both sides

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= \log x + 1$$

$$f'(x)=f(x)(\log x+1)$$
$$f'(x)=x^x(\log x +1)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The relevant information has been updated on it. I'm just a little curious. I'm not a professional. I'd like to know some other possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: most of the time, $a^b$ is defined as $e^{b\log(a)}$. So while it is possible to compute the derivative of $x^x$ using differentiation from first principles, it is also possible to compute it directly using the chain rule.

Comment: I don’t know if this process is right or wrong, it seems to be very troublesome. But you can quickly judge the limit by impression.Updated above

Comment: I think this requires other proofs and other conditions,such as e................